# Not able to see programmatic ConstraintLayout guidelines in LayoutEditor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have extended ConstraintLayout and added a few guidelines in code. I am able to align the views based on these guidelines in xml but I am not see these guidelines in the layout editor.

Comment: didn't get your exact issue share your code to identify your exact issue..?

Comment: Everything you add in code(Java) will only be created at runtime. So they will not show up in your layout editor - because they aren't there until you run your app.